# R - Bucketing entities for multiple columns in a data table

Tags: r

I intend to count entities based on buckets defined for the metrics(columns).

The base data table:

[image]

I need a count of entities based on defined buckets as
-100 to -20, -20 to -10, -10 to 100 , for each column.

So, I guess the final output could be displayed as

[image]

`dput` of the raw data:

```
structure(list(Entity = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), `Peak%` = c(22, 
30, 15, -9, -22), `30Day%` = c(-53, -31, 3, -32, 7), `60Day%` = c(-50, 
-46, 18, -35, -6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: `cut` and `findInterval` are made for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain empty levels, here is a very similar `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)
lapply(dat[-1], cut, breaks = c(-100, -20, -10, 100), labels=c("Low", "Mid", "High")) |> 
as.data.table() |>
melt(, measure=1:3, value.factor=TRUE) |> 
dcast(value ~ variable, drop=FALSE, fill=0, fun=length)
#>    value Peak% 30Day% 60Day%
#> 1:   Low     1      3      3
#> 2:   Mid     0      0      0
#> 3:  High     4      2      2
```

*Edit:*

Based on the modified question, this would be one option:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
    Grp=rep(c("Texas", "Colorado"), each=3)[1:5],
    Entity = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
    `Peak%` = c(22, 30, 15, -9, -22), 
    `30Day%` = c(-53, -31, 3, -32, 7), 
    `60Day%` = c(-50, -46, 18, -35, -6)), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, (colnames(dat)[-c(1:2)]) := lapply(dat[, -c(1:2)], cut, breaks = c(-100, -20, -10, 100), labels=c("Low", "Mid", "High"))]
melt(dat, measure=3:5, value.factor=TRUE, value.name = "Ranges") |> 
dcast(Grp + Ranges ~ variable, drop=FALSE, fill=0, fun=length)
#>         Grp Ranges Peak% 30Day% 60Day%
#> 1: Colorado    Low     1      1      1
#> 2: Colorado    Mid     0      0      0
#> 3: Colorado   High     1      1      1
#> 4:    Texas    Low     0      2      2
#> 5:    Texas    Mid     0      0      0
#> 6:    Texas   High     3      1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! if I had an additional column that defines 'groups' for entities; for ex. A,B,C belong to 'Texas', and D,E belong to 'Colorado' , how can I modify the above snippet, that shows an additional column 'groups'  in the final dataframe as well?

Comment: Thnx. Is there anyway to avoid using "|>"? I keep getting parse error when I use it outside Rstudio in other programs...

Comment: Sure: either nest the commands, or create an intermediate variable (i.e. `dcast(melt(dat, measure=3:5, value.factor=TRUE, value.name = "Ranges"),
    Grp + Ranges ~ variable, drop=FALSE, fill=0, fun=length)` or `tmp <- melt(dat, measure=3:5, value.factor=TRUE, value.name = "Ranges"); dcast(tmp, Grp + Ranges ~ variable, drop=FALSE, fill=0, fun=length)`, respectively). Alternatively, load the `magrittr` library and replace `|>` with `%>% `.

Answer (score 1):

### base R and reshape2

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(dat[-1], cut, breaks = c(-100, -20, -10, 100))) |>
  reshape2::melt(c()) |>
  reshape2::dcast(value ~ variable)
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#        value Peak. X30Day. X60Day.
# 1  (-10,100]     4       2       2
# 2 (-100,-20]     1       3       3
```